# Stirling approximation producing a different output than expected

Tags: c

So I am new to C and slowly learning the syntax. I have come across a problem though. So I am trying to prove Stirlings approximation where

ln (N!) = N ln (N) - (N)

So when I make print statements within the code to test whether each element of the array is producing the output of the array is the number I want it to be. It's far from it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double * natural_log ();
/* Obtain the natural log of 0 to 100 and then store each value in an array     */
double * approximation ();
/* Use the sterling approximation caluculate the numbers from 0 - 100 and then store it in an array */
double * difference ();
/* Calculate the difference between the arrays */
double * percentage ();
/* Calculate the percentage of the difference and return the array */

int main () {
   natural_log ();
 /*  approximation (); */
   return 0;
}

 double * natural_log () {

    static double natural_array[101]; /* set up the array */
    int i; /* set up the integer to increase the array by a value */


    natural_array[0] = 0.0; /* set up the first value in the array */
    natural_array[1] = log(2);

    double x;
    x = natural_array [1];
    for (i = 2; i <=100; i++) { /* set up the for loop to increment the i */
        natural_array[i] = x + log(1 + i);
        x = natural_array[i];
        **printf ("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, x);**
     }
    return natural_array;
}

double * approximation () {

    static double approximation_array[99]; /* set up the array */
    int i;  /* set up the integer to increase the array by a value */

    for (i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
        approximation_array[i] = (i) * log(i) - (i);
    }
    return approximation_array;
}
```

With the print statement in bold it produces this output

```
 Element[2] = 688
 Element[3] = 2048
 Element[4] = 1232
 Element[5] = 688
 .....
 .....
 Element[100] = 544
```

I am certain that these are numbers it's not supposed to be spitting out on the output so can anyone explain why it is? Thank you!

Comment: `natural_array[99];` must have `101` elements to be indexable by `100`, as a side issue.

Comment: Your arrays have 99 elements, with indexes 0 to 98. Your loops goes up to index 100 which is element 101. Indexing out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not printing the right data type with

```
printf ("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, x);
```

which wants to print an `int` type. Please try

```
printf ("Element[%d] = %e\n", i, x);
```

You must also declare the array thus

```
static double natural_array[101];
```

Either that, or reduce the loop limit. It is better to tie the two perhaps like this

```
#define ELEMENTS 100
...
static double natural_array[ELEMENTS]; 
...
for (i = 2; i < ELEMENTS; i++) { 
    ...
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I guess it was more simple than I figured

Comment: Minor: Given the wide variety of numeric results, recommend `"%e"` over `"%f"`.